# On Keras, what's the difference between running a model.fit on n epochs vs. running n times model.fit on 1 epoch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When training a model, I often use the `epochs=` attribute of `model.fit` method, like the following:

```
model.fit(x, y, epochs=100, ...)
```

But I saw some kernels on Kaggle using the `for` loop approach, like this:

```
for i in range(0, 100):
  model.fit(x, y, epochs=1, ...)
```

Intuitively, I would say they are different because `model.fit` can perform some kind of parameters initialization, but I might be wrong.

Can anyone point out the difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. When you run `model.fit()` the weights are getting initialized by specified weights initializer or by default initializer if none is specified. Maybe you can disable weight initialization somehow but I think it's much easier to just do it with specified number of epochs rather then in loop.